# Executing remote command using PXSSH in Python

Tags: python, server

I am trying to make Python script that will remotely start upgrade procesure of a program located on server. The upgrade procedure actually  starts, but does not finish. It acctually exits immediately after start.
Here is my code:

```
import pxssh
w=pxssh.pxssh()
w.login('15.24.22.10','root','pass')
w.sendline('cd /home/incoming/')
w.prompt()
w.sendline('./upgrade')
w.prompt()
w.wait()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To debug: you can get all the conversation printed on stdout by using `import sys` and `w=pxssh.pxssh(logfile=sys.stdout)` instead of `w=pxssh.pxssh()` at the start.

Comment: Tnx. I found the prblem. I needed to send '\n' for next step of procedure